# What is the Quran interpretation for psychedelic therapy since the law makes it nearly impossible to receive it?

Tags: halal-haram

I am aware that that there has been some scientific research on the use of psychedelic for mental disorders but other than the US, and anyway as a last resort, it seems impossible to have medical supervision for it.

I have found myself (before conversion) extraordinary benefits and no side effects whatsoever of "self psychedelic therapy", managing to overcome some very serious issues such as decade long depression, addiction,... Yet, there are issues I am still working on.

On the other hand traditional therapy such as psychotherapy, or prescription drugs, always failed with me.

It seems the Quran doesn't talk about medical use of psychedelics but scholars interpret it the way it is "halal" if under medical supervision.

**But if the medical supervision is impossible to get (for example in most or all of EU), does Quran still say it's forbidden, no matter the documented (and self experienced) benefits?**

Answer (score 1):

Asalaam Alaikum

first and foremost let us look at the definition of psychedelic,

as a noun its defined as ' a psychedelic drug',

as an adjective its defined as 'relating to or denoting drugs (especially LSD) that produce hallucinations and apparent expansion of consciousness'.

Psychedelics (also known as hallucinogens) are a class of psychoactive substances that produce changes in perception, mood and cognitive processes. Psychedelics affect all the senses, altering a person's thinking, sense of time and emotions.

so now that we have a clear understanding of the subject matter, let us look into references from quran and authentic sunnah, insha Allah.

there are 4 verses relating to intoxicants (khamr) in quran and numerous authentic hadith narrations. tendency to normalise the use or find an excuse for the abuse of such substances are derived from the verse about intoxicants in chapter 2 [baqarah] in quran.

They ask you about wine and gambling. Say, "In them is great sin and [yet, some] benefit for people. But their sin is greater than their benefit." And they ask you what they should spend. Say, "The excess [beyond needs]." Thus Allah makes clear to you the verses [of revelation] that you might give thought. [2:219]

to understand and to derive a verdict from quran we must know the concept of 'naskh' (abrogation). as Allah the mighty and sublime says in the quran,

We do not abrogate a verse or cause it to be forgotten except that We bring forth [one] better than it or similar to it. Do you not know that Allah is over all things competent? [2:106]

after gradual forbiddance of intoxicants, the final verse was revealed in surah al-maidah.

O you who have believed, indeed, intoxicants, gambling, [sacrificing on] stone alters [to other than Allah], and divining arrows are but defilement from the work of Satan, so avoid it that you may be successful. [5:90]

from the quran it is very clear and definitive that all intoxicants are 'haram', this is made more clear through our beloved prophet (P.B.U.H). i have found more than 400 hadith forbidding the use of 'khamr' (intoxicants) in the major compilations of hadith books. i'll try to list a very few that is relevant to your question, insha Allah.

It was narrated that Ibn 'Umar said:
"Every intoxicant is Khamr and every intoxicant is unlawful"

Grade:   Sahih (Darussalam)
Reference    : Sunan an-Nasa'i 5699

It was narrated that Ibn 'Umar said:
"Intoxicants are unlawful in small or large amounts"

Grade:   Sahih (Darussalam)
Reference    : Sunan an-Nasa'i 5698

in the authentic sunnah (whatever is reported from the Prophet) explains that the word "Khamr" applies to all that makes a person lose their mind. Any substance that intoxicates and befogs the mind is considered Khamr and is unlawful, even if it is given another name.

It was related by Imam Abu Dawud on the authority of Abu Malik Al-Ash`ary (may Allah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (peace be upon him) said, "Indeed, some people of my Ummah (nation) will drink Khamr, calling it by another name." This Hadith is classified as Sahih (authentic) by Ibn Hibban. (Part No. 22; Page No. 106)

from this it is very clear that be it psychedelics or any other type of mood/mind altering substances is not allowed in islam. being supreme in His authority, Allah alone knows the real wisdom behind all divine imperatives, but a close look into the Islamic legal code reveals that the Shari'ah of Islam has left ample room for human emotions when following its dictates. this is to give man the least possible inconvenience.

islam prioritizes the well being and health of its people. therefore in the aspect of health, muslims are required to take care of their body entrusted by Allah s.w.t. to always be in good health.However, in our enthusiasm of taking care of our health and finding medicine to cure a disease, the question of halal and haram still need to be taken care of. searching and opting for halal medicine is a must to all muslims. keeping away from haram is also our responsibility. this coincided with the words of the Prophet “searching for halal is obligatory to every muslim” hadith narrated by al-Baihaqi.

“Allah has sent down both the disease and the cure, and He has appointed a cure for every disease, so treat yourselves medically, but use nothing unlawful” narrated by Abi Darda r.a.

so seeking medical treatment is mandatory upon every muslim if it becomes unbearable but we must remember that it is Allah that cures us, not the medicine/therapy or the doctor. in order to fully comprehend the usage of divergent medicinal treatments in islam we have to understand the concept of regularity (azimah) and leniency (rukhsakh).for example, during emergency or crisis, muslims must break their fast if they are sick or they can consume pork during famine . it is mandatory for Muslims to hold onto azimah except when there is an emergency that will allow leniency. emergency simply means a condition in which the person faces a situation involving the safety of their life or property.

Wahbah al-Zuhaili, a professor of Islamic law at Damascus University has given an expansive and clear definition of emergency which is,

"Emergency is an occurrence to a person, a dangerous situation or severe distress, which may lead to injury or illness to life, body, dignity, sense or property and everything connected to it. At the time, it is a must to conduct haram or abandon the mandatory or delay the time, in order to prevent harm from occurring by consideration within the scope of Islamic law”.

here i emphasize and stress on the fact that we should not simplify the leniency given by Islamic law using emergency as an excuse. the understanding of 'halal' and 'haram' in medicine is very important and we must always try to avoid the doubtful. trust in Allah the mighty and sublime to cure you, try not to resort to such therapy or medicines.you may think its good or has benefits for you but let me remind you of a verse in quran,

..... But perhaps you hate a thing and it is good for you; and perhaps you love a thing and it is bad for you. And Allah Knows, while you know not.[2:216]

may Allah show you mercy and guide you to the straight path.

Allah knows best.